# eclipse plug in: open editor with python syntax highlighting programmatically

Tags: python, eclipse, plugins

I'm developing an eclipse plug in from which I'm opening external files in an eclipse editor like this:

```
            IFileStore fileStore = EFS.getLocalFileSystem().getStore(fileToOpen.toURI());
        FileStoreEditorInput editorInput = new FileStoreEditorInput(fileStore);
        IWorkbenchPage page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();

        try {
            page.openEditor(editorInput, "org.eclipse.ui.DefaultTextEditor");
            TextEditor editor = (TextEditor) PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().getActiveEditor();
            IDocument document= editor.getDocumentProvider().getDocument(editor.getEditorInput());
            editor.selectAndReveal(document.getLineOffset(line - 1), document.getLineLength(line-1));

        } catch ( PartInitException e ) {
            //Put your exception handler here if you wish to
        } catch (BadLocationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

That works actually fine. But some of the files are *.py files, Python code and I would like to have the text highlighted as in the PyDev editor for example.

I guess I need to open a different editor?! But I have no clue how or where to find it.

Any hint is much appreciated! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The editor id for the pyDev python editor seems to be `org.python.pydev.editor.PythonEditor`. So if you have pyDev installed you could try specifying that editor.

Note: Not all editors support editing external files. Some only work on files in the workspace or have reduced functionality on non-workspace files.